# How to grab the value of one of the cells of the parent gridview when accessing the child gridview?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a common JavaScript function to expand and collapse a child gridview within its parent gridview. My problem is that I want to grab the value of one of the cells of the current row in the parent gridview, or at least its row index. Nothing I have tried seems to work - I keep getting the value or row index of the current row of the child gridview.

Here is my aspx with the JavaScript function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function divexpandcollapse(divname)
        {                        
            var div = document.getElementById(divname);
            var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);
            if (div.style.display == "none")
            {
                div.style.display = "inline";
                img.src = "minus.gif";             
            }
            else
            {
                div.style.display = "none";
                img.src = "plus.gif";          
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

          <div>
            <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" value="" />

            <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" DataKeyNames="OrderID" Width="750px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvOrders_RowDataBound" GridLines="None"
                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" BorderColor="Blue" style="z-index: 100; left: 126px; position: absolute; top: 96px" BackColor="White" OnRowCommand="gvOrders_RowCommand"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvOrders_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#E1E1E1" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="LightBlue" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("OrderID") %>');">
                            <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("OrderID") %>" width="9px" src="plus.gif" alt =""/>
                        </a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="20px" />
                    <ControlStyle BackColor="Black" />
                </asp:TemplateField>                
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="Order ID" >
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="Customer ID" >
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Company" HeaderText="Company" >
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Order Date" >
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ShippingDate" HeaderText="Shipping Date" >
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>                
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="100%">
                            <div id="div<%# Eval("OrderID") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">
                               <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderStyle="Double"  BorderColor="#df5015" GridLines="None" Width="700px"
                                    OnRowCancelingEdit="gvChildGrid_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="gvChildGrid_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvChildGrid_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvChildGrid_RowUpdating" >
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#E1E1E1" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CoreID">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCoreID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CoreID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxCoreID" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 0px; position: relative" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("CoreID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxCoreID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CoreID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BoxID">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblBoxID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BoxID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxBoxID" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 0px; position: relative" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("BoxID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxBoxID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BoxID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CoresPerBox">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCoresPerBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CoresPerBox") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxCoresPerBox" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 0px; position: relative" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("CoresPerBox") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxCoresPerBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CoresPerBox") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PalletID">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblPalletID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PalletID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxPalletID" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 0px; position: relative" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("PalletID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxPalletID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PalletID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BoxesPerPallet">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblBoxesPerPallet" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BoxesPerPallet") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxBoxesPerPallet" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 0px; position: relative" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("BoxesPerPallet") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxBoxesPerPallet" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BoxesPerPallet") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowCancelButton="True" CancelText="Cancel" HeaderText="Edit Controls" />
                                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#8080FF" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

And part of my code behind:

```
protected void gvChildGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView gv = (GridView)gvOrders.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gvChildGrid");

            GridViewRow parentRow = (GridViewRow)gv.Parent.Parent;

            int indexRow = int.Parse(parentRow.RowIndex.ToString().Trim()); //gvOrders.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString().Trim());

            //int indexRow = parentRow.RowIndex;
```

I have tried using a hidden field, grabbing the value of the evaluated variable in the gridview template field, and several other ways. Since the expand/collapse is handled by JavaScript, I can't figure out how to access the parent gridview by "normal" means, such as _IndexChanged or _RowCommand.

I just stuck the code I was trying to use in the _RowEditing method for convenience, until I could figure out how to make it work. I know that by doing this, e pertains to the child gridview. The two commented out lines are commands that either didn't work or just grabbed the current row of the child gridview.

I will admit that I am relatively new to C# (but not to programming), and realized that I am probably just missing something. But I can't for the life of me figure out what.

Comment: what you mean by current row ?

Comment: and which column you want to get its value ?

Comment: You said :
My problem is that I want to grab the value of one of the cells of the current row in the parent gridview, or at least its row index.
Do you mean :
My problem is that I want to grab the value of one of the cells of the current row in the parent gridview FROM child gridview , or at least its row index.
?

Comment: @Navid - by current row, I mean the row in the parent gridview that I clicked to bring up its associated rows in the child gridview. I want to get the value of the second column (1), which is the order number.

As for my problem, I'm using a javascript function to expand and collapse the child gridview when I click on the +/- sign in the first column of the parent gridview. I need a way to get the value of one of the cells of the current row in the parent gridview when I click one of those buttons.

Comment: Normally, I would just use a select link and _rowcommand or _selectedindexchanging with two gridviews, but my boss wants a nested gridview, which I lack experience with.

Comment: He asked that I work with this example: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20047/Editable-Nested-GridView-All-in-One), which is giving me problems converting to our needs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can solve your problem:
With RowDataBound event you can access each row in server-side:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("myLabelId")).Attributes.Add("data-customAttribute", ((Order)e.Row.DataItem).OrderNo);
        }
    }
```

You see you can add a Label(or any control) to a TemplatedField (e.a with ID of myLabelId), then you can add html attributes to that label or do any changes you want based on your data.In the example data-customAttribute added to the control.You can even add onclick attribute to know whether the row is current or not. You can access data from e.Row.DataItem then you have to cast it to your data object (e.a Order).

With Jquery you can access the label in clientSide :

```
// get all rows in table including header
var $rows=$('#<%=gvOrders.ClientID%>').find('tr');

// access the innerHTML of Label control we created before which contains the OrderNo
var OrderNo=$(aRow).find('#myLabelId').html();
```

Note that ClientID returns the html Id of any server control and you can access it by document.getElementById or $('#id').

I hope this tips could help you.

Comment: Thanks, Navid! This looks interesting... I'm going to try to implement this and see if it works.